# Fluent NHibernate With Dynamic Table Name

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

how can I map a dynamic table name to a entity? 
Ex, I can have many tables, all have the same structure, however, has its different name, how can I map this using Fluent NHibernate?
remembering that before compiling I do not know the name of these tables.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with your design in the first place - why do you need to have the same structure within different tables? Isn't it better to have a single table, but with a type field?

Comment: I need because the quantity of tables are dinamicaly, and the location of this table too, in another DB or not.

Comment: I still would suggest you to try to review your design - usually even if you have different quantity of data - if it has the same structure you still can keep it in a single table. But if you really need dynamic mapping - you should aim the answer Cole has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll probably need to do is put a place holder in the fluent nhibernate mapping for the table name and then replace it after you build the mappings.

Take a look at the following article and I think the first code sample will give you an idea of what you need to do.

http://ayende.com/blog/3294/dynamic-mapping-with-nhibernate

I was able to do this.  Here is a rough example:

```
var fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure(NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure())
      .Mappings(m =>
          m.FluentMappings
          .AddFromAssemblyOf<OrderMap>()
          .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<PascalCaseColumnNameConvention>())
          .ProxyFactoryFactory("NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate");

var config = fluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration();

foreach(PersistentClass persistentClass in config.ClassMappings)
{
    if(persistentClass.MappedClass == typeof(Order))
    {
        persistentClass.Table.Name = "Dynamic Table";
    }
}

//You could substitute above for each loop with linq unless you have a bunch to replace then use foreach
//config.ClassMappings.First(x => x.MappedClass == typeof(Order)).Table.Name = "Dynamic Table";

var sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();

using(ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    Order order = session.Query<Order>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```